# Jenkins "Failed to create a temporary file in /" Why is it trying to write a file there?

Tags: java, jenkins

Yesterday `Jenkins` was great. Today all builds fail.

```
Jenkins Version 1.650
All plugins up to date.
Latest CentOS. Fully patched.
Jenkins installed via yum.
```

When trying to get console output of the job I just ran, the web console states there is no log:

```
No such file: /1/log
```

When I look at `/var/log/jenkins.log`:

```
Feb 24, 2016 9:06:16 PM jenkins.model.PeepholePermalink updateCache
WARNING: Failed to update hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@24ab29e4[rails-server] lastFailedBuild permalink for null
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in /
```

So looking at this log I'm wondering, why is Jenkins trying to write anything to `/?` Is that the literal `/`, not a relative path? Sure looks like it. That's not OK, so how do I fix it?

```
Environment vars: 

Name  ↓   Value   
_   /etc/alternatives/java
HOME    /var/lib/jenkins
LANG    en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME jenkins
NLSPATH /usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
PATH    /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD /
SHELL   /bin/bash
SHLVL   3
TERM    xterm-256color
USER    jenkins
XFILESEARCHPATH /usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
```

Permissions on /var/lib/jenkins are correct. `/tmp` is writeable and the jvm is using `/tmp` for `java.io.tmpdir`

I gave Jenkins permissions to write to `/` to see what would happen when a build occurs. It wrote the following files:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jenkins jenkins    2 Feb 24 21:47 lastFailedBuild -> 10
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jenkins jenkins    2 Feb 24 21:47 lastUnsuccessfulBuild -> 10
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins    4.0K Feb 24 21:47 10
```

Comment: `JENKINS_HOME` should point to the directory where Jenkins keeps its state, often _/var/lib/jenkins_. Is JENKINS_HOME set under System Properties? How did you launch Jenkins?

Comment: It also looks like you are setting `PWD to /`. While I have a background with both *nix and windows I've never used Jenkins on anything but windows, but that looks like a good place to start.